# React-native-map marker color is not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I want to change the color of the marker sequentially. when the App is firstly rendered all of the colors of the marker should be red. after one second later first marker(no-1) color want to be blue. then after the one-second first marker color goes to previous state color. but the second marker (no-2) marker goes to blue.

for example - we have six marker

`In one-second - blue -red -red -red -red- red
In two-second - red -blue - red -red -red -red
In three-second - red -red -blue -red -red -red
In four-second - red -red- red -blue -red -red
In five-second - red -red- red -red -blue -red
In six-second - red -red- red -red -red -blue`

here is my code - the active state is changing but not the color of the marker.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,Animated, Platform } from 'react- 
native';
import MapView, {AnimatedRegion,Polyline} from 'react-native-maps';

export default class App extends React.Component {
 state = {
currentLongitude: 'unknown', 
currentLatitude: 'unknown',
startTransition: 0,
endTransition: 5,
  markers: [{
    title: 'lat: 28.6095206, log: 77.1011353',
    index: 0,
    active: false,
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 28.6095206,
      longitude: 77.1011353,

    },
  },
  {
    title: 'lat: 28.6151759, log: 77.0842171',
    index: 1,
    active: false,
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 28.6151759,
       longitude: 77.0842171,

    }, 

  },
  {
    title: 'lat: 28.6242541, log: 77.0652866',
    index: 2,
    active: false,
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 28.6242541,
       longitude: 77.0652866,

    }, 

  },
  {
    title: 'lat: 28.6328224, log: 77.0863152',
    index: 3,
    active: false,
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 28.6328224,
       longitude: 77.0863152,

    }, 

  },
  {
    title: 'lat: 28.6364551, log: 77.0968294',
    index: 4,
    active: false,
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 28.6364551,
       longitude: 77.0968294,

    }, 

  },
  {
    title: 'lat: 28.6364551, log: 77.0968294',
    index: 5,
    active: false,
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 28.6109522, 
      longitude: 77.1131802,

    },   
  }, 
 ]
};

componentDidMount = () => { 
this.animate()
};
// shouldComponentUpdate(){
//   return false
// }

async animate() {
 const {markers} = this.state;
 for(var i in markers){
  if(markers[i]['active'] == true){  
    const newItems = [...this.state.markers];
    newItems[i].active = !newItems[i].active;
    this.setState({marker: newItems})   
  }

}

if(markers[this.state.startTransition].index==
this.state.startTransition){
  if(markers[this.state.startTransition].active==false){
    const newItems = [...this.state.markers];
      let index = this.state.startTransition

      newItems[index].active = !newItems[index].active;

      this.setState({ markers:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newItems)) 
   });    
  }

 }

if(this.state.startTransition < this.state.endTransition){

  let currentTransition = this.state.startTransition + 1;
  this.setState({startTransition: currentTransition});

} else {
  this.setState({startTransition: 0});
}
let x = setTimeout(()=>{

  this.animate()
 }, 1000);
}


render() {
const {currentLatitude} =  this.state;
const {currentLongitude} = this.state;
const Latitude = parseFloat(currentLatitude)
const Longitude = parseFloat(currentLongitude)

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <MapView
    style={styles.map}
     region={{
      latitude: 28.6095206,
      longitude: 77.1011353,
      latitudeDelta: 0.155,
      longitudeDelta: 0.151,
    }}
  >

    {this.state.markers.map(marker => (

 <MapView.Marker.Animated 
  coordinate={marker.coordinates}
  title={marker.title}
  key = {marker.index}
  pinColor={marker.active==true?'blue':'red'}
/>
))
}


     <Polyline
coordinates={[
{ latitude: 28.6095206, longitude: 77.1011353 },
{ latitude: 28.6151759, longitude: 77.0842171},
{ latitude: 28.6242541, longitude: 77.0652866},
{ latitude: 28.6328224, longitude: 77.0863152},
{ latitude: 28.6364551, longitude: 77.0968294},
{ latitude: 28.6109522, longitude: 77.1131802 } ]}
    strokeColor="#000" 
    strokeColors={[
        '#7F0000',
        '#00000000', 
        '#B24112',
        '#E5845C',
        '#238C23',
        '#7F0000'
    ]}
    strokeWidth={6}
  /> 
      </MapView>
     </View>
    );
   }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
     justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
   map: {
    flex: 1,
     ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
   },
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

**Changing the marker key property to something different**

```
<Marker
  pinColor={marker.active==true?'blue':'red'}
  key={`${marker.index}-${marker.active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}`}
  // ... other props ...
/>
```

check this [link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/887) also

Comment: what is the use of the key here?  how it will help me to change the color of the marker?

Comment: if key is same then marker will not re-render - it is used for optimisation to avoid re-rending

Comment: Thank you.. Animation is working now on android. But not on the IOS phone. Just  Map is opening,  animatiom is not working on IOS device..is there any reason?